# Trigger functions via specific URLs

Tags: google-apps-script

I am very new to this and any help if greatly appreciated!

I have been working through many different options, but have run into issues with everything I have tried. At this point I am looking to **scrape** what I have and ask for advice. I have several functions in a script that roll up into a web app with buttons to run each function. I am looking to make specific URLs for each function to run each time the URL is called upon.

Comment: It's only possible to create one url per Apps Script file associated with the published web app.  But, you can append a search (query) string to the url, and the search string can have multiple different parameters, each with a different value associated with it.  If you make a POST request to `doPost()` you can send a payload.  A search string is appended to the url with the syntax `url?keyName=Value1&keyName2=value2`  For information about how to get the search string from the published url, search the documentation for "Event Objects"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call the function in server side script : Google App Script when I hit a hyperlink in Gmail body (client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950204/how-do-i-call-the-function-in-server-side-script-google-app-script-when-i-hit)

Comment: Previously I was working with searchStringName to append my URL, but ran into many issues. As I mentioned, I am very new, doing my best to learn. Thank you so much for the guidance! Ill check into these items and post back with results.