# Google script run after email confirmation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

In this case, I don't have a code or screenshots to share because I honestly don't know how to even start it :)
We have a spreadsheet (Google Sheets) which have numerous scripts built into it. They run mainly based on form submission and don't require any further confirmation after a form is submitted. For this new form we wish to implement, we would like to script to run only after a user has confirmed via email. Here's the rundown:

1. User A (normally from the administration department) will input data into a form.
2. Once form is submitted, this data will be sent to another user (User B) for confirmation. We would like this process to happen over email, and not directly via Google Sheets prompt.
3. Once User B confirmed data is good, a script will run to compile the data and perform several actions on it.

No problem to send an email via script but how do we include a confirmation button/link to it and how do we capture this clink to continue the compiling of this data?

Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call the function in server side script : Google App Script when I hit a hyperlink in Gmail body (client side)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950204/how-do-i-call-the-function-in-server-side-script-google-app-script-when-i-hit)

Comment: Hi @TheMaster and thanks for this reference. Indeed it seems to be a very similar situation which is mentioned by Rebeca in that answer. However, this didn't solve my problem as both the question, and your following answer, lack some general context before and after these scripts. I'm a hobbyist coder so I usually require wider explanation than my fellow pros on this site.... :) It's important to note that our situation doesn't require an approval chain. It'll be just one single approver. Not sure if this changes anything regarding the route I need to take on this project. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. User A Enters data into Form and Presses Submit
2. FormSubmit Script recovers data and sends email to user B
3. User B reviews data and Presses a link on the email which sends a request via a web app to complete the transaction at a later time.

You can probably customize the webapp link with query string parameters so that the transaction can be completed without any further interaction but it will probably take a couple of days of programming to complete and test the job.

Comment: I'd love a "couple of days" challenge! :) However, I'm still not sure how to even begin :) As mentioned in my comment above to @TheMaster, I'm a hobbyist so forgive my somewhat lack of knowledge in what might be a rather simple project

Comment: I often start projects without knowing how to begin.  But I begin anyway and I'd recommend that you do the same.  Dive into the documentation at every turn and ask questions here at SO when necessary.